# QUdpSocket only receives the first 2 datagrams

Tags: c++, qt, qudpsocket

I wrote a program for transmitting pictures via UDP in Qt. I encountered a problem that QUdpSocket does not accept an image larger than 50 kb. I decided to split the image into several datagrams and send it. As a result, the required number of datagrams is sent, and, as I understand it, only the first two are received. Why is this happening and do you have other options to solve the problem?

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "udp_server.h"
#include "udp_client.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    UDP_Server server(2323);
    UDP_Client client(2323);

    server.show();
    client.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

udp_server.h and udp_server.cpp:

```
#ifndef UDP_SERVER_H
#define UDP_SERVER_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QBuffer>
#include <QFile>

class UDP_Server : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit UDP_Server(int port, QWidget *parent = nullptr);

private:
    QUdpSocket* socket;
    QLabel* showLabel;


private slots:
    void slotProcessDatagrams();

};

#endif // UDP_SERVER_H

//================================

#include "udp_server.h"

UDP_Server::UDP_Server(int port, QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget{parent}
{
    setWindowTitle("SERVER");

    socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    socket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, port);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(slotProcessDatagrams()));

    showLabel = new QLabel;

    QVBoxLayout* box = new QVBoxLayout;
    box->addWidget(showLabel);
    setLayout(box);
}

void UDP_Server::slotProcessDatagrams() {
    QByteArray datagram;
    QPixmap frame;

    while (socket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        QByteArray receivedData;
        receivedData.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
        socket->readDatagram(receivedData.data(), receivedData.size());
        datagram.append(receivedData);
        qDebug() << "read: " << receivedData.size();
    }

    if (frame.loadFromData(datagram, "PNG")) {
        showLabel->setPixmap(frame);
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Failed to read frame";
    }
}
```

udp_client.h and udp_client.cpp:

```
#ifndef UDP_CLIENT_H
#define UDP_CLIENT_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QBuffer>
#include <QFile>

class UDP_Client : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit UDP_Client(int port, QWidget *parent = nullptr);

private:
    QUdpSocket* socket;
    int port;

private slots:
    void slotSendDatagram();

};

#endif // UDP_CLIENT_H

//================

#include "udp_client.h"

UDP_Client::UDP_Client(int port, QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget{parent}, port(port)
{
    setWindowTitle("CLIENT");

    socket = new QUdpSocket(this);

    QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton("Send");
    connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(slotSendDatagram()));

    QVBoxLayout* box = new QVBoxLayout;
    box->addWidget(btn);
    setLayout(box);

}

const int UDP_DATAGRAM_SIZE = 50000;

void UDP_Client::slotSendDatagram() {
    QFile file("path/to/image");
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        while (!file.atEnd()) {
            QByteArray datagram = file.read(UDP_DATAGRAM_SIZE);
            socket->writeDatagram(datagram, QHostAddress::LocalHost, port);
            qDebug() << "send: " << datagram.size();
        }
        file.close();
    }

}
```

output from qDebug():

```
send: 50000
send: 50000
send: 50000
send: 24753

read: 50000
read: 50000
Failed to read frame
```

Also, if you try to send a picture weighing less than 50 kb or more than 50 kb but less than 100 kb (to make 2 datagrams), then everything is sent and received normally

Comment: Are you aware that your datagram of size 50000 will be broken up into 1500ish-byte chunks? What is your strategy for dealing with packets arriving out of order, multiple times or not at all?

Comment: I just started writing this program and wrote this for a test and it doesn’t work. Probably, along with the main data, I will send an id packet for gluing in order, and if the packet does not arrive, then discard the image

Comment: Okay, onto the second problem then: you cannot assume that all datagrams have arrived at the moment readyRead fires. You now need to solve the framing problem so the receiving side knows when your message (image) has been received correctly. And preferably completely.

Comment: Plus, the kernel is free to drop UDP packets if the kernel-side buffers are full, which isn't surprising when sending multiple 50k packets

Comment: Overall, UDP is entirely the wrong protocol for what you are trying to do. Just use TCP. Simply send the image size before the image data so that the receiver knows how much data to read

Comment: Or use the HTTP(s) protocol?